# How to access a data file in a plugin generator?

Tags: plugins, jekyll

I'd like to access a data file I have in the _data folder and use this in a plugin generator, but I'm not sure how. I have:

```
site.data.projects.each do |project|
  ...
end
```

But when I try to compile it tells me "undefined method 'projects' for Hash(...) NoMethodError.  What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2):

If you post what your `_data` file looks like I can give you a better answer, but try:

```
site.data['projects'].each do |project|
  ...
end
```